# Populating a Many to Many Through Relation in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, sails.js

Sails.js offers a way to populate objects in Many to Many relationship via its Blueprint API. Thus, `GET /categorymodel/:categoryid/productscollection` will return all products that belong to the specified category. [Link](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/Populate.html).

For Many to Many Through relations, the docs advises to use multiple One to Many relations via an intermediary model to achieve the desired organization. The downside of this is there's no way to populate objects via the built-in Blueprint API. [Link](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ThroughAssociations.html).

So, while querying for products belonging to a particular category, I query `GET /categorymodel/:categoryid/intermediarycollection` to get something like

```
[{categoryid: 1, productid: 1, id: 1}, {categoryid: 1, productid: 2, id: 2}, {categoryid: 1, productid: 3, id: 3}, ... n]
```

This means the client will have to `GET /products/:productid` n times.

How do I process the populate() result (and not edit/override it) to add the product object before sending to the client? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I have a similar problem where I want to emit an event after the blueprint assembles its data (in my case for the purposes of activity logging). For now, I think I'm stuck with copying the Sails blueprint controllers verbatim.

Comment: Just as a side note you don't have to **GET /products/:productid** n times.

Do a **GET /products/** with a WHERE IN clause and an array of ids (and an appropriate limit). Then on the front end set the products based on the results. It'll save you a ton of network overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible, but it is kind of an hack..?

The underlaying behaviour of the blueprints, is to call `res.ok` on your result from database. What if we changed the behavior of `res.ok`, and added a filter or similar custom needs?

Take a look on this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41932352/36975