# Sails blueprints lifecycle

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I need to add some additional data to result of `find` blueprint. I found this solution:

```
module.exports = {
  find: function(req, res) {
    return sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.find(req, res);
  }
}
```

but I can`t find any way to change response here, or add callback into the blueprint. I even try to change blueprint and add the cb in it:

```
module.exports = function findRecords (req, res, cb) { 
  ...
  if (typeof cb === 'function') res.ok(cb(result));
  else res.ok(result);
```

but in this case it returns 500 statusCode every time (but with corresponding data)

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? Do you want to add data to response or to headers? Why are you adding a callback?

Comment: @zabware I want to add statistic info (count for associated table) to the results of blueprints. I need this in several controllers, so just copy/paste code from `find` blueprint isn`t really good.

Comment: To populate info from an associated table is easy. 
First: verify that the table are really associated (example: models/Article.js: module.exports.attributes { ..., user = {model: 'User'}})
Second: make sure `sails.config.blueprints.populate` is set to true.

http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/populate-where

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with the same issue for a couple of time. Here is my hack (with explanation) to solve this.

The build in blueprint will always make a call to `res.ok`, `res.notFound`, or `res.serverError` if an error occurs. With altering of this method calls, it is possible to modify the output.

```
/** 
 * Lets expose our own variant of `find` in one of my controllers
 * (Code below has been inserted into each controller where this behaviour is needed..)
 */
module.exports.find = function (req, res) {

    const override = {};
    override.serverError = res.serverError;
    override.notFound = res.notFound;
    override.ok = function (data) {

        console.log('overriding default sails.ok() response.');
        console.log('Here is our data', data);

        if (Array.isArray(data)) {
            // Normally an array is fetched from the blueprint routes
            async.map(data, function(record, cb){

                // do whatever you would like to each record
                record.foo = 'bar';
                return cb(null, record);

            }, function(err, result){
                if (err) return res.error(err);
                return res.ok(result);
            });
        }
        else if (data){
            // blueprint `find/:id` will only return one record (not an array)
            data.foo = 'bar';
            return res.ok(data);
        }
        else {
            // Oh no - no results!
            return res.notFound();
        }
    };

    return sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.find(req, override);
};
```

Comment: Thanx. Can I override ok method directly in res?
`res.ok = function (data) {...};
return sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.find(req, res);`

Comment: Yes @Crusader, this sounds like a better idea! This way any other dependencies on the `res`-object will still work. (But I havn't actually tested your proposal.)

Comment: Where do you put this file?

Comment: Directly into the controller @pondermatic (together will all the other exports).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like only copy-paste solution existed. So I copy all code from files in node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions to the actions of every controller and then change it.